# App working in Microsoft App Center but not Google Play Store Open Test

Tags: android, google-play, google-apps, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center

I recently created an Android app which currently works great with Microsoft Visual Studio App Center. Now, I want to test it with Google before eventually releasing it. However, I am encountering a problem that though it works with App center, when I try to run an open test with Google (has gotten reviewed and approved), I get the error Äpp cannot install"This problem happens on all the devices I have, and I am not sure how to resolve the issue. I am uploading the same APK file (though I also send an extra one to the Google Play store).

Has anyone encountered this problem before or know of a solution (not sure if this helps but for reference [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ShootHoops.wizardEVP.FelgoCompetitiveBallTryOne) is the open test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this seems to happen on iOS as well, if you have installed an app either from your IDE in debug mode, or from App Center, App Store and Google Play will refuse to install the "official" app afterwards. (Im guessing either versioning(you have same version) or signing issue(if you let google sign your apk it might look different from what app center does)

Anyway, I always just uninstall what I have before(the dev/test app) and install always goes fine afterwards...